# how to type sudo password when using subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess, call

i defined a function that switch my proxy settings every now and then,
problem is that i want it to run in a loop without manual intervention. But when i execute the program in sudo it gets called the first time en runs smoothly, second time it asks me for my sudo password. Here is the bit of code:

```
def ProxySetting(Proxy):
    print "ProxyStetting(Proxy)"
    call("networksetup -setwebproxy 'Wi-Fi' %s" "on" % Proxy, shell = True)
    call("networksetup -setsecurewebproxy 'Wi-Fi' %s" "on" % Proxy, shell = True)
    call("networksetup -setftpproxy 'Wi-Fi' %s" "on" %Proxy , shell=True)
```

I could use threading but am sure there is a way of doing it that wont cause problems. How can i hard code my sudo password so that it runs at the beginning of the function?

Comment: It's better to create a service using **systemd** and add the permissions on the service configuration file.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but you might want to have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44540122/7738328 which talks about using `sudo` in a `subprocess`. But, as mentioned above, it is better if you can completely avoid using `sudo` for command execution.

Comment: Simply put this code won't run unless I type my password. I want to automate that script meaning never have to manually type that password. I will try Mikael solution, but would rather not have to add permissions to every file that requires a root command.

Comment: But what you probably want even less, is to have your `sudo` password in clear text in your Python script.

Comment: Probably adding your file to sudoers will help.

Comment: You guys are definitely correct, hard coding my password sounds stupid. but this code is only going to run on my raspberry pi nothing of real value on it.

Comment: Also instead of hardcoding it i will put it as raw_input() in the starting of the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running a command as a super user from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you can execute a command sudo without interactive prompt asking you to type your password :

```
from subprocess import call    

pwd='my password'
cmd='ls'

call('echo {} | sudo -S {}'.format(pwd, cmd), shell=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It should be noted that storing your password in plaintext in your code is a security issue and generally bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Another method of passing your password to a shell command through python that wouldn't involve it showing up in any command history or `ps` output is:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', self.resubscribe_script], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('{}\n'.format(self.sudo_password))
```

Note that using `communicate` will only allow one input to be given to stdin; there are other methods for getting a reusable input.

Comment: What `self` means in the OP question?