# Running command with os.popen with sudo in python

Tags: python, popen, sudoers, virsh

I have a command `/usr/bin/virsh dumpxml <UUID>` that I need to run inside of a python program, the thing is that the command needs to run like `sudo -u <user> sudo /usr/bin/virsh dumpxml <UUID>`, I try to call it with the following code:

```py
cmd = "sudo -u <user> sudo /usr/bin/virsh dumpxml %s" % uuid
data = os.popen(cmd).read()
...
```

But I'm getting an error message indicating that the domain is not found, but, if I run the same command from the bash, it works fine.

The `/usr/bin/virsh dumpxml` command is inside the /etc/sudoers.d/

Also, I need to run with the second '**sudo**' because if not, it won't work

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, I doubt if you really need the second sudo in your command.  Also, your text indicates that a UUID is required at the end of the command, but you aren't passing one in your code.

Comment: sorry about that, updated

Comment: probably is better to use subprocess library

Comment: check this - >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684764/how-to-type-sudo-password-when-using-subprocess-call